# Scale subview to parent size

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints

I have a view controller:

[image]

And root view controller:

[image]

Red part is a UIView. In this view i add ViewController with following code:

```
scannerVC.removeFromParentViewController()
scannerVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
self.addChildViewController(scannerVC)
self.searchContainer.addSubview(scannerVC.view)
scannerVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
self.searchContainer.layoutIfNeeded()
```

And this is what i see:

[image]

How can i scale my view to parent view size and how to remove right margin ? `Autoresize Subviews` enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you'd do it for any subview / superview pair: Set the `frame` of `scannerVC.view` to the `bounds` of its superview `self.searchContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simplify things here. Using IB you can add to your root view controller a Container View that allow you to embed another view controller. The child VC will adjust the size to match the Container View.
Hope it helps.

@matt's answer is valid as well, but I think this will save you from any code.